# Spark SQL view and partition column usage

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, partitioning

I have a Databricks table (parquet not delta) "TableA" with a partition column "dldate", and it has ~3000 columns.
When I issue `select * from TableA where dldate='2022-01-01'`, the query completes in seconds.

I have a view "view_tableA" which reads from "TableA" and performs some window functions on some of the columns.
When I issue `select * from view_tableA where dldate='2022-01-01'`, the query runs forever.

Will the latter query effectively use the partition key of the table? If not, if there is any optimization I can do to make sure partition key is used?

Comment: In your view query, is the window function applied _after_ you filter by `dldate`? Because if not, then spark probably needs to read all of the data anyways. Check the query plan, maybe you will be able to find an optimization for you query.

Comment: It worked after adding dldate to all the window functions, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If partitioning of all window functions is aligned with table partitioning, optimizer will be able to push down the predicate to table level and apply partition pruning.

For example:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT *, sum(a) over (partition by dldate) FROM TableA)
 WHERE dldate = '2022-01-01';

== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- Window [dldate#2932, a#2933, sum(a#2933) ...], [dldate#2932]
   +- Sort [dldate#2932 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      +- Exchange hashpartitioning(dldate#2932, 200), ...
         +- Project [dldate#2932, a#2933]
            +- FileScan parquet tablea PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(dldate#2932), (dldate#2932 = 2022-01-01)]
```

Compare this with a query containing window function not partitioned by dldate:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT *, sum(a) over (partition by a) FROM TableA)
 WHERE dldate = '2022-01-01';

AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- Filter (isnotnull(dldate#2968) AND (dldate#2968 = 2022-01-01))  << !!!
   +- Window [dldate#2968, a#2969, sum(a#2969) ...], [a#2969]
      +- Sort [a#2969 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
         +- Exchange hashpartitioning(a#2969, 200), ...
            +- Project [dldate#2968, a#2969]
               +- FileScan parquet tablea PartitionFilters: []  << !!!
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense, my current window functions are not using partition key, but It can be changed to add partition key along with the current set of columns, let me try this out and post my results here, Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Yes, this works as expected. In all the windows functions, I added dldate(partitionkey column) as part of the partition by specification and now the view is also using the partition column effectively,Thanks Kombajn zbożowy